# CME error when saving components with required metadata

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme, schema, hotfix-rollup

I'm seeing an strange error when trying to save components using a schema with mandatory embedded metadata schemas.

The problem comes when trying to create a new component with this schema. I can create schemas without mandatory embedded schemas without problem.

On saving the component the following error is returned in the CME:

`XML validation error. Reason: The element 'Metadata' in namespace 'http://[domain.com]/schemas/[schemaname]' has invalid child element 'Priority' in namespace 'http://[domain.com]/schemas/[schemaname]'. List of possible elements expected: 'Type, Classification' in namespace 'http://[domain.com]/schemas/[schemaname]'.`

This is on 2013 SP1  which has just had HR1 applied.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that having a keyword field in the metadata of a component causes this problem after HR1.

Hotfix [CME_2013.1.1.88649 available https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2013_SP1_HR1/index.aspx](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2013_SP1_HR1/index.aspx) fixes the issue.